# I want to quick sort using linked lists

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, quicksort

Write a function that takes two student record structures by reference and swaps all their contents except their next pointers. Use your functions to implement bubble sort algorithm to sort the linked list (do not use arrays).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*defined a structure for date of birth*/
struct birth{
int date;
int month;
int year;
};
struct studentrecord{
char name[64];
struct birth dob;
int height;
float weight;
struct studentrecord *next;
struct studentrecord *prev;
};

struct studentrecord* printlist(struct studentrecord* p){
if(p==NULL)
return 0;

printf("%s\t%2d%2d%4d\t%d\t%.2f\n",p->name,(p->dob).date,(p->dob).month,(p-
>dob).year,p->height,p->weight);
printlist(p->next);
}
/*swapped all the contents of 2 student records*/
void swap(struct studentrecord *c,struct studentrecord *d){
char temp[32];
strcpy(temp,c->name);
strcpy(c->name,d->name);
strcpy(d->name,temp);

int f;
f=(c->dob).date;
(c->dob).date=(d->dob).date;
(d->dob).date=f;

 int m;
m=(c->dob).month;
(c->dob).month=(d->dob).month;
(d->dob).month=m;

 int y;
y=(c->dob).year;
(c->dob).year=(d->dob).year;
(d->dob).year=y;

int h;
h=c->height;
c->height=d->height;
d->height=h;

float w;
w=c->weight;
c->weight=d->weight;
d->weight=w;
}
/*comparing the age of 2 students*/
int compareage(struct studentrecord *a, struct studentrecord *b){
if (a->dob.year<b->dob.year)
    return 0;
else if(a->dob.year>b->dob.year)
    return 1;
else if (a->dob.month<b->dob.month)
    return 0;
else if(a->dob.month>b->dob.month)
    return 1;
else if (a->dob.date<b->dob.date)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
}
/*Here is where i think the problem starts*/
struct studentrecord *partition(struct studentrecord *l, struct 
studentrecord *h)
{
// set pivot as h element
int x  = h->dob.year*10000+h->dob.month*100+h->dob.date;

// similar to i = l-1 for array implementation
struct studentrecord *i = l->prev;
struct studentrecord *j ;
// Similar to "for (int j = l; j <= h- 1; j++)"
for (j= l; j != h; j = j->next)
{
    if ((j->dob.year*10000+j->dob.month*100+j->dob.date)<= x)
    {
        // Similar to i++ for array
        if(i == NULL)
            i=l;
        else
            i=i->next;

        swap(i, j);
    }
}
if(i == NULL)
   i=l;
else
   i=i->next;
// Similar to i++
swap(i, h);
return i;
}

void quicksort(struct studentrecord *start,struct studentrecord  *last){
if(last != NULL && start != last && start != last->next){
 struct studentrecord *pi;
 pi = partition(start,last);
 quicksort(start,pi->prev);
 quicksort(pi->next,last);
}
}

struct studentrecord *read(int n){
struct studentrecord *s;
if(n==0){
    return NULL;
}
s=(struct studentrecord*)malloc(sizeof(struct studentrecord));
scanf("%s%d%d%d%d%f",s->name,&(s->dob.date),&(s->dob.month),&(s-
>dob.year),&s->height,&s->weight);
s->next=read(n-1);
return s;
}
int main(){
struct studentrecord *k, *temp1,*temp2;
int n, i;
printf("please enter the number of student records\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
k=read(n);
temp2=k;
k->prev=NULL;
while(k->next!=NULL){
    temp1=k;
    k=k->next;
    k->prev=temp1;
}
temp1=k;
quicksort(temp2,temp1);
printlist(temp2);
}
```

I think there is some problem with my partition and quicksort functions(and hence the main function). I don't think i am doing it correctly and am getting a bit confused on how to sort the list. Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: bubble sort or quick sort?

Comment: @coderredoc quick sort. Since i have partition and a pivot like thing in my code

Comment: It would be simpler and clearer to use structure assignment to swap the two structures, and then swap back the two pointers, wouldn’t it?  Is it okay to swap the previous pointers?  The assignment says yes, but…

Comment: The quoted assignment says “bubble sort” and no arrays.  Quick sort really wants to work on arrays.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it clearly mentions not to swap the pointers...

Comment: You have a `compareage()` function, but you don't use it.  Why not?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I think I have become so confused, i am not really able to figure out what to write in my main function...

Comment: See also [Sorting a linked list using merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459941/sorting-a-linked-list-using-merge-sort) by the same OP.

Comment: The code fixing up the previous pointers in the list belongs in the `read()` function rather than in `main()`, but the rest of what is in `main()` is more or less OK.  I'd probably read to EOF rather than demanding a count of the number of records, but I like to make my computers do the counting for me.

Comment: The code is unpleasant to attempt reading, not least because it is not indented.  You get more help if your code looks good.  When it looks like a mess, people are less inclined to spend time trying to work past the mess.